# Clicking the modal link the second time doesn't call the controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap modal that is populated by a partial view when I click the link to open it. The link to the modal references to an action which returns the partial view which is loaded inside the body of the modal. Clicking the modal link the first time fires the action method but when I close the modal and open it the second time, the modal opens but the action method  doesn't get called. It's important to call the action method every time as the content of the modal body will change. Here's the html to call the partial view method:

```
<a href="/Administrators/Users/ClinicListModal/28" class="modal-link">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
</a>
```

Here's the action method I'm trying to call:

```
public ActionResult ClinicListModal(int id)
{
    return PartialView("_ClinicListModal", DataProvider.GetUserClinicsByID(id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    //remove modal content
      $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal').find('.modal-content').empty();
});
```

This will empty modal's content each time modal is not visible (=closed). When content is not visible, action on controller gets called.